# How to stop the thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-runonuithread

I have a thread in my callback function as follows:

```
@Override
public void onConnectError(final BluetoothDevice device, String message) {
    Log.d("TAG","Trying again in 3 sec.");
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   //Do something 
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
}
```

I will to close the the above thread when I press the back button or onDestroy. How can I do it. Thank you

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Close or distroy the thread
 }
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Close or distroy the thread
 }
```

Comment: you want to stop Handler?

Comment: Your `Runnable` only runs once.

Comment: Because the `onConnectError` is automatically called when bluetooth connection is lost. So, I saw the log every 2 second. How can I stop it. It may be from Handler

Comment: @user8264 ok I am adding my answer with some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do this like

```
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;

@Override
public void onConnectError(final BluetoothDevice device, String message) {
Log.d("TAG","Trying again in 3 sec.");
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler = new Handler();
runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
//Do something
        }
    };
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
    }
});
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (handler != null && runnable != null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
 }
```

and same in onDestroy();

Answer (score 1):

I'm mostly use thread in this way.See its independent in activity

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.abc);

    holdConnectionHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

}

Handler holdConnectionHandler = new Handler() {

public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
// do some work 

    holdConnectionHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 10 * 1000);
}
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();

holdConnectionHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
// or 
holdConnectionHandler.removeMessages(0);

}
}
```

Thanks hope this will  help you

Comment: holdConnectionHandler  is a local variable in `ononConnectError`. How can I call it in my o`nDestroy` function

Comment: its not local, you can use it like any method, try it once and let me know if you stuck anywhere.

Comment: Could you see my main function in onConnectError and use for method in that function? I will test it

Comment: you want to do something that depends on you variables BluetoothDevice device, message ?

Comment: please check  i have updated my answer. How it work in activity. Handler  independently work.

Comment: Start it in your onconnectionerror and call it on destroy with check if it does not equal to null then  remove call backs